# Перенос комментариев в чат не обрабатывает тревогу

Tags: дефект, инструменты-модератора, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

Вот я перенёс комментарии в чат, причём воспользовался той кнопкой переноса, которая стоит у тревоги, а тревога при этом осталась - пришлось жать ещё одну кнопку. Как-то это нелогично - очевидно же, что действие лишнее.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: На MSE сразу задавай вопрос. У нас такое никто не исправит (: